# How to draw a line on the LinearLayout?

Tags: android, line, android-linearlayout

Do you know how to draw line on the `LinearLayout`? To create a `LinearLayout`, I am using a xml resource:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    //I wanna draw line on "linear"
}
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways; one way is to define a `ShapeDrawable` representing the line in XML (in your `res` folder) and set that as the background resource of say, an `ImageView` inside the `LinearLayout`.

You can read more about drawables and 2D graphics in general in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).

Feel free to provide some more context (specific use case) so I could elaborate on this answer or others could answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created an image in an image editing tool that was a 2x2 pixel square of the color I wanted.  Then in code I created an ImageView and set that image as the source.  Lastly I set the ImageView height to FitContent and the width to FillParent and that gave me a horizontal line.