# Draw line on the background

Tags: android

I am searching about draw line on the background of LinearLayout.

I've add sub views to my LinearLayout. Now I am trying to draw line on the background.

Is is possible ?

If so, How can I do ?

Please help guys.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951213/how-to-draw-line-on-the-linearlayout

Comment: Yeap, little different. That is about drawing line on the sub view. 

This question is drawing line on the background of LinearLayout.

It seems that same subject on both.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to subclass the view and implement onDraw.  Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, you might try simply setting the background to an image with the line already drawn.